# How to get Azure AD Refresh token with Postman?

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-storage, refresh-token

I try to get Refresh token with Postman using the following data:
[image: Postman UI]

and get a response:

[image: Response]

What is wrong I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the scope as `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` instead of `https://storage.azure.com/.default`.

I tested the same in my environment and faced the same issue as well as you can see below:

[image]

As a Solution , I changed the scope as I have mentioned and I was successfully able to get the token and test the same for your requirement as well.

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

Please make sure to add `callback_url` that postman uses `(i.e. https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback)` in the reply url of the Azure AD app as shown below:

[image]